# ClickOnce & XNA issues

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, xna

I essentially have a blank XNA project built using the XNA 3.1 wizard, i'm testing whether a game i make can be "installed" on another computer without having to make them install everything manually to make it work.

The only additional code in the game is:

```
Components.Add(new GamerServicesComponent(this));
```

After going through the ClickOnce publishing stage i copied it to a USB drive and attempted to run the "setup.exe" on a Windows Vista computer with no Visual C#/Studio or XNA installed.

According to the MSDN entry the ClickOnce will actually include everything necessary to make the game work on the computer, yet after the installation i get the dreaded "... has stopped working" when i try to run it.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I assumed the reason it says it can be done is because it works.

Thanks

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464156.aspx

Edit:

Just noticed that the article states that the Games for Windows - LIVE is not included in the distributable, would this mean if it was included as a component in the XNA game it would cause the crash when i attempt to run it?

Comment: The "...has stopped working" is usually an uncaught exception. Try starting the program from a command-line. This may give you the exception details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an application says "has stopped working" for no immediately apparent reason, that's usually a sign that an unhandled exception has occured. Since MSDN states that the GamerServicesComponent class [is not available without the XNA Game Studio installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.aspx), that seems like the most plausible explanation.

Why is it available, then? Well, you need something to program up against; you wouldn't be able to use auto-completion and such if you didn't have the class, because VS wouldn't know what it looked like

Getting it to compile for, say, XBox 360, where I would guess that the class CAN be used, probably wouldn't work either if it didn't know anything about the class.

Comment: It can be used if you have XNA installed to test the Gamer singing in/out etc.., the entire game can then easily be converted to an Xbox 360 game instead of having to redeploy it to the Xbox360 after every change.

If i was to use the same component and deploy it to the Xbox 360 it would simply link into the existing Guide used on the Xbox dashboard.

Thanks for the answer though, it only seemed to click for me after writing the post.

Answer (score 0):

To address the general problem of a ClickOnce application which "has stopped working" immediately, you can get more information on your particular problem by looking in the Windows Event Viewer:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-Event-Viewer

Like Michael mentioned, this is often an unhandled exception, but this way you can see WHAT the unhandled exception was.